# Basic limit terminology question

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, terminology

If at $c$ the left and right limits of a function $f$ differ, then referring to *the* limit of $f$ at $c$ makes no sense.

The correct assertion is that $f$ has *no* limit at $c.$ But, considering that $f$ has both left and right limits at $c,$ saying that $f$ has *no* limit at there sounds somewhat inaccurate, doesn't it? On the other hand, it would be criminal to claim that $f$ has *two* limits there.

Analogy: I have a left hand and also have a right hand, but I don't necessarily have *a* hand?

Comment: (This question was recently edited. I didn't see the question when it was originally asked.) The terms *unilateral limit* (or *one-sided limit*) and *bilateral limit* (or *two-sided limit*) are often used, and for the situation you bring up one would say that both unilateral limits exist and the bilateral limit does not exist.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for introducing the terms! But that doesn't negate the above linguistic conundrum. I would explain it as being due to the fact that while the "left" in "left hand" is sort of like a nonrestrive 'clause' that expands on the meaning of the phrase "left hand", the "left" in "left limit" is sort of like a restrictive 'clause' that qualifies the meaning of the phrase "left limit". Or to put it another way: "I have a hand, and it is left." Whereas "I have a left-limit, but it's not necessarily a limit per se." Perhaps adding the hyphen in such a case is a good idea!

Comment: I was in kind of a hurry this morning when I read your question and wrote my comment, and I apparently didn't internalize very well your "left hand" and "right hand" comment, since the analogy now seems to me to be misdirected (as I think you're also thinking). You might find the notion of a cluster set at a point of interest. I posted a short expository essay about it in this [26 January 2007 Math Forum AP-Calculus post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5501984).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro My left-hand-right-hand example was deliberately absurd; the point being: if "left limit" and "left hand" aren't linguistically analogous, it sure isn't clear off the bat! p.s. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case the limit does not exist (which is the same as saying that the limit is non-existent). The reason is that limit has a precise meaning and one-sided limit also has a precise meaning. A function having a one-sided limit, or even both one-sided different limits does not qualify as f having half of its limit. The definitions are clear as are the implications: If the limit exist then the one-sides limits exist as well and are equal to the limit. Consequently, if the one-sided limits exist and are different then the limit does not exist.